# Strange behaviour when moving objects

Tags: modeling, rigging

I'm still pretty new to blender, so there is a non-zero chance I've just messed up somewhere along the line, but perhaps there is a quick fix for this issue:

If the objects all stay within this exact location, everything is fine:

[image]

But as soon as I move things...

[image]

Oh. Oh, dear.

Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening? I tried clearing location data for everything, but that didn't do the trick...

Side info: There are armatures within the 'rays' and the legs. These armatures are connected to null objects, which are connected to bezier circles.But since I'm moving the null objects and circles at the same time, I figure that's probably not the issue.

Everything except the legs is parented to the sphere. The sphere and the legs are parented to the null object above. This behaviour also happens without the null object above.

EDIT: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YYIWJUDQ1jcl7DZpnChaZhQSRThpUjsX/view?usp=sharing  Here is the file. There's a walking animation. I just want to move it along the X-Axis without that somehow breaking it.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file and explain what you're trying to do with your object?

Comment: I've added the file and the intention to the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. unparent all empties from "Empty" (your parent) who have a follow path constraint because they will already be moved automatically by that constraint
2. name your objects accordingly so that you yourself and others can understand what you did and what the objects are for (e.g. rename Empty to "Master controller" and if you wanna be a real good citizen, move empties (controllers) to an own collection called "controllers"

then you will get:

[image]

Comment: That is so obvious in retrospect, thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome